# Getting the following Error: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:

Tags: python

I am new with Python and I am attempting to extract a specific column from a csv file (Column name = "Hostname"). I keep getting error: **FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified**:

#################################################

```
import os

import pandas as pd

data_location = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\Marco A\\Desktop\\csv_files\\Status_CS.csv')

df_total = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Hostname"])

for file in os.listdir(str(data_location)):

    df_file = pd.read_csv(data_location + file)
    selected_columns = df_file.loc[:, df_total]
    df_total = pd.concat([selected_columns, df_total], ignore_index=False)

df_total.to_csv("ValuableColumns.csv", index=False)
```

Error states its in line 10 ("**for file in os.listdir(str(data_location)):**") I have also attempted the following code in line 10 "**for file in os.listdir(data_location):** however, I get the following error:

line 11, in 
for file in os.listdir(data_location):
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not DataFrame

Not quite sure how to proceed. Please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Instead of linking to your code, would you mind editing your post and typing it out?

Comment: @DanielWalker I have included the code

Comment: Why are you using pandas for this?  What do you gain?  How many columns are in your CSV?  **What are you actually trying to do?**  Your description does not match your code.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am eventually going to merge several csv files into one master csv file which is why you are seeing "import pandas as pd". Right now all I am trying to do is select a certain column from a csv file (column name = "Hostname") and put it onto another csv file. Hence, df_total.to_csv("ValuableColumns.csv", index=False).

Comment: If that's ALL you want, it's one line: `data_location['Hostname'].to_csv("ValuableColumns.csv",index=False)`.

Comment: I will use that as reference @TimRoberts but unfortunately, that did not work for my script. I got error: "TypeError: "string indices must be integers". Not quite sure why that is.

Comment: If that's true, then your code does not look like you have above.  Perhaps you should revise your question with what you're using now.

Comment: @TimRoberts the code above is exactly what I have. I appreciate your help but, there is no need to revise my question. I am attempting to extract a specific column from a csv file (with the code above) however, I am getting a "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified:" error. like stated above.

Comment: You can see that `data_location` is a DataFrame.  It is not a string.  Doing `os.listdir(str(data_location))` will never work, because `data_location` does not contain a path.  It contains a DataFrame.  Now if you want to loop through the rows of that DataFrame and use a value from one column, that would be sensible.

Comment: What, EXACTLY, does `Status_CS.csv` contain?  Why are you trying to use it as a directory path?

Comment: @TimRoberts I see, thank you for that clarification. Also, Status_CS.csv contains a lot of data such as device names, company names, software versions, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reading the content of the .csv file in the variable `data_location`. Then, you are calling `os.listdir()` using the content of the .csv file, and this is not a string directory but a data frame so it will throw an error.

The variable `data_location` must be a string containing the path of the directory that you are trying to list its files.

Comment: I have changed line 6 with: data_location = r'C:\Users\Marco A\Desktop\csv_files\Status_CS.csv' but now I am getting "NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Marco A\\Desktop\\csv_files\\Status_CS.csv'" for line 11. Also when I attempt to change line 11 FROM "for file in os.listdir(data_location):" TO "for file in os.listdir(str(data_location)):" OR "for file in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Marco A\Desktop\csv_files\Status_CS.csv')" I get the same error.

Comment: What directory are you trying to list? The path 'C:\Users\Marco A\Desktop\csv_files\Status_CS.csv'  is a file and not a directory. If you want to list all other files in the directory csv_files for example then use data_location =  r'C:\Users\Marco A\Desktop\csv_files\